# How do I apply border to a flow on click?

Tags: ruby, border, shoes

I've got this piece of Shoes app:

```
flow :top => 10, :left => 10 do
  flow :width => 0.3 do 
    para @board.deck.card
    click do
      if @board.source_pile
        @board.source_pile = nil
        @deck_border.hide
      else
        @board.source_pile = @board.deck
        @deck_border = border yellow, :strokewidth => 2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to apply border only to the second flow, but for some reason the border appears around the whole application. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoes has [tricky blocks](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Rules.html).  In a nutshell, in blocks, `self` typically refers to the application.  To counter this, we'll have to create a variable to hold the flow we want to border:

```
flow :top => 10, :left => 10 do
  inner = flow :width => 0.3 do 
    para @board.deck.card
    click do
      if @board.source_pile
        @board.source_pile = nil
        @deck_border.hide
      else
        @board.source_pile = @board.deck
        @deck_border = inner.border yellow, :strokewidth => 2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ahhh nice :D I tried to do 
flow do |inner|
but that didn't work. Thanks!